# Why cant I write to a socket's input stream java

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

So I Have two Similar classes to test Sockets that are the same from the lines down.

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket socket =new ServerSocket(80);
        Socket client = socket.accept();
        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
        InputStream txt = System.in;
        Scanner text = new Scanner(txt);
        while (true) {
            if (text.hasNext()) {
                out.write((text.next()+"\n").getBytes());
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Sent");
            }
            if (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
                System.out.println("Received");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Socket socket =new Socket("localhost",80);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
        InputStream txt = System.in;
        Scanner text = new Scanner(txt);
        while (true) {
            if (text.hasNext()) {
                out.write((text.next()+"\n").getBytes());
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Sent");
            }
            if (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
                System.out.println("Received");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is two way messaging.
When I type in either shell it says sent, however no text shows on the other shell.
Why are they not sending or receiving any text?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works for me. What **exactly** did you type into each processes `text` Scanner.

Comment: I only typed "test".